# fullcalendar not showing time before 10am

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Hi Every i am working with fullcalendar in my frontend to display the time slots. I am sending json data to fullcalendar config and it is displaying all the time slots expet the time before 10 though the json data present.

[image]

And my calendar config is

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        defaultDate: $scope.today,
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month'
        },
        allDaySlot: false,
        eventClick: function (eventsFeed) {
            $scope.openApptDetails(eventsFeed);
        },
        minTime: "07:00:00",
        maxTime: "21:00:00",
        contentHeight: "auto",
        resources: resourcesFeed,
        events: eventsFeed
    });
```

So can any one please help me why calendar not displaying time slots before 10am.

json data :

```
event: {color:"green",end:"2018-04-18T10:00:00",resourceId:1,start:"2018-04-18T9:00:00",studentName:"",title:"Available",tutorName:"",type:"",}

resource: {id:1,title:"Timmy Tutor"}
```

I am using FullCalendar v3.6.1

Comment: can you please provide your sample event and resource JSON (as actual text,not a picture), then we can try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have provided sample json data and version i am using in my question. Thank you @ADyson

Comment: As requested please provide the resource JSON as well. Thanks.

Comment: Please check now @ADyson

Comment: try **2018-04-18T09:00:00** instead 2018-04-18T9:00:00

Comment: Roy is right, whatever code is generating your date strings is producing it in an unrecognised format. fullCalendar accepts all the string formats which momentJS accepts, which is documented here https://fullcalendar.io/docs/moment and in more detail here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/

Comment: Thats really good catch for me @Roy  That solved my problem. I sliced data and forgot about the time. Thanks you very much

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight too @ADyson

Comment: My advice would be to generate your dates using a proper date library, it sounds like you're doing something with strings which isn't a great idea. Leads to this kind of annoying error. Or if you're writing your JSON by hand, don't do that either

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and i agree with you @ADyson I am going to use moment library to handle date part

Answer (score 1):

Try `2018-04-18T09:00:00` instead `2018-04-18T9:00:00`
There is a missing **0** in Hours.

Comment: it's work but, this is not the real fix for the problem. How we can make it work even there is no 0 ?